# AC PCB trace width?

Tags: pcb-design, relay

I want to design a 2 channel relay for 250V AC max 10A. The PCB is 1.6mm thick and 1 oz copper. I have given 3mm width traces on both top and bottom layers which connect the end terminals to the relay pins. The traces are 5cm long and isolated with board cut throughts. While using the trace width calculator, i got the nominal width to be 1.5mm. But I have seen that in sonoff basic and all they have exposed such traces as pad and put additional solder on it. Is this recommended or 3mm width is sufficient?

Comment: Where did you get 0.16 mm from?

Comment: A basic trace width calculator gives me over 7.5mm for 10A / 1oz / 10°C. 0.16mm seems very low.

Comment: Can you share the calculation? I believe I chose the thickness of the board as 1.6mm and you would have gone with 1oz/ft.

Comment: It is the copper thickness that is relevant, not the board thickness. https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-pcb-trace-width